# How to insert column_name as string in procedure while dynamically selecting value through select query which is containing same column_name

Tags: plsql

dummy table

```
row_id   information_date
1        10-oct-1987
2        NULL
```

tbl_error

```
row_id       column_name
2            information_date
```

```
create or replace procedure test(column_name in varchar2)
as
begin
    insert into tbl_error 
    values(select row_id , column_name from dummy where column_name IS 
NULL);

end;
end test;
```

--calling

```
call test('information_date');
```

OUTPUT

```
tbl_error
row_id     column_name
2          NULL
```

I want to log 'information_date' into tbl_error but when executing it is storing NULL because it is taking value from dummy how to insert as string.

Desired output

```
ROW_ID  COLUMN_NAME
2       INFORMATION_DATE
```

Comment: Your insert statement in the procedure is wrong. That won't even compile.

Comment: it is working fine but storing null value

Comment: I don't see how an invalid statement could run at all. The syntax **is** invalid and will throw an error. (Hint: when using SELECT for an INSERT you must not use VALUES)

Comment: in insert statement i m using values

Answer (score 0):

solution is

```
insert into tbl_error 
    values(select row_id , chr(39) || column_name || chr(39) from dummy where column_name IS NULL);
```